# Application becomes irresponsive on InputStream.read();

Tags: java, sockets, javafx, networking

When the code reaches the **InputStream.read()**, the application becomes iresponsive.

I think maybe that is the case because the client code runs before the server code and it waits for the input.

Here is the server code
When login button is clicked then the case is **"Send login details"**(*It sends the login details to the client*) and if the id and password is correct then the case becomes**"Login successful"**. It is sending correct value in **output.readUTF();**

```
public void doWork(String line) {
    Connection conn = Main.getConnection();

    switch (line) {
        case "Send login details":

            Main main = new Main();
            String details = main.giveLoginDetails();
            String id = " ";
            String password = " ";
            int i = 0;
            while (details.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                id = id + details.charAt(i);
                i++;
            }

            try {
                id = id.trim();
                password = details.substring(i + 1);
                System.out.println(id + " " + password);
                output.writeUTF(id + " " + password);

            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }break;


        case "Login successful":


                        String getDet1 = "SELECT * FROM $t;";
                        if(su == 1)
                        getDet1 = getDet1.replace("$t", "Post1");
                        else
                         getDet1 = getDet1.replace("$t", "Post"+(su*10+1));
                        System.out.print(getDet1);
                        rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(getDet1);
                        String d;
                        int dd;
                        for (int x = 0; x < ch; x++) {
                                rs2.next();
                                d = rs2.getString(2);
                                output.writeUTF(d);
                                System.out.println(d);
                                dd = rs2.getInt(3);
                                output.writeInt(dd);
                                System.out.println(dd);
                                d = rs2.getString(4);
                                output.writeUTF(d);
                                System.out.println(d);
                                d = rs2.getString(5);
                                // if(d == null) {
                                //   output.writeUTF("null");
                                //   System.out.println("null");
                                // }
                                // else
                                output.writeUTF(d);
                                // System.out.println(d+"not null ");}

                        }
                    }
                    catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;


            }
    }
```

Client code:- Another scene after the login scene.
It is the Initialize method of Initializable interface. Here i am reading the output but it hangs.

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
String posts = "";
int ch = 0;
    Main m = new Main();
    Stage stage = m.getStage();
    stage.setResizable(true);

    int c = 0;

        try {
            posts = Networking.input.readUTF();
            ch = Networking.input.readInt();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int rs = Integer.valueOf(posts);


        for(int k = 0; k<rs; k++) {
            c++;
            }
        try {
                Networking.input.readUTF();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String det = "";
            int cl;
            for (int i = 0; i < ch; i++) {
                a[i].setDisable(false);
                a[i].setOpacity(1);
                try {
                    Networking.output.writeUTF("send voting details");

                    det = Networking.input.readUTF();
                    System.out.println(det);

                    cl = Networking.input.readInt();
                    System.out.println(cl);

                    det = Networking.input.readUTF();
                    System.out.println(det);

                    det = Networking.input.readUTF();
                    System.out.println(det);


                }
                catch (IOException exx)
                {
                    exx.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
```

**Add:**
Here is my Networking class

```
package sample;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Networking {
public static ServerSocket serverSocket= null;

public static void connect(int port)
{
    try
    {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.print("Server is started");

        while (true)
        {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                Thread thread = new ServerThread(socket, input, output);
                thread.start();
                System.out.print("Client Accepted");
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
    catch(IOException exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: If you're executing this I/O code on the _JavaFX Application Thread_ then your application will be unresponsive. **Never** block, or execute long running work on, the FX thread—the FX thread is integral to the rendering process. Move this I/O work to a background thread. But remember to update the UI, if necessary, on the FX thread. See [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm)

Comment: I am running it on a new thread.

Comment: You must be blocking or monopolizing the FX thread _somewhere_ if your application is unresponsive. Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue. Note that `initialize` will be invoked on whatever thread invoked `FXMLLoader#load`.

Comment: Your `connect` method uses a `while true`. This is most likely your problem. Why do you need to create an unlimited amount of sockets and Threads?

Comment: @Sedrick I need it because i want to connect many clients to a server. There was an extra InputStream.read() in my code which was creating the problem. Thanks for your valuable time.